# Spherical harmonics integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, integration, mathematics, spherical-harmonics

I've been struggling with this integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta~ e^{-i\phi} Y_{l m}(\theta,\phi) Y^*_{l'm'}(\theta,\phi) ~d\theta ~d\phi
$$
I've tried to use the definition of the spherical harmonics as
$$
Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi) = N e^{i m \phi} P^m_l(\cos\theta) $$
with $N$ being the normalization constant.

I was planning to use the (partial) orthogonality of the associated Legendre polynomials $P^n_l$ but I was unable to make any further progress. How do I go around solving the given integral?

Comment: Try to write $\sin \theta e^{-i\phi} Y_{lm}$ as a linear combination of other spherical harmonics (recursive relation of legendre polynomials?) and then use orthogonality of spherical harmonics

Comment: Another possibility is to use that an integral over three spherical harmonics has a well known value, often called a Gaunt coefficient.

Comment: I thought about this but $e^{-i \phi} Y_{lm} = N P^m_l e^{i m \phi} e^{- \phi} =  N P^m_l e^{i (m-1) \phi} =  N P^m_l e^{i (m-1) \phi} \neq Y_{l m-1}$

Comment: I didn't notice I can use to \sin\theta to identify with another harmonic and then use the $3J$ symbols relation, thank you